# django: redirecting to another app's view not properly

Tags: python, django

App1 containing the form, after user fulfills and submits the form, the page will redirect to "Result" which is defined in App2

```
def input(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = Inputform(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 

            cd = form.cleaned_data
            print (cd['company'])
            print (cd['region'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('result', args=(p.id,)))
```

The url is as below:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^result/$','result.views.resultlist',name='result'),
    url(r'^input', 'inputform.views.input',name='input'),
```

The thing is if I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/result on the browser, it works properly. But once I fulfill the form and click the submit, the page will redirect to:http://127.0.0.1:8000/result.html. And then there is error showing:
The current URL, result.html, didn't match any of these.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's weird that http://127.0.0.1:8000/result is working, since that url route is not defined in your urls.py. It should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/result_list/ 

Please provide more info on the urls.py

Comment: And please show your template. Did you perhaps put "result.html" in the action attribute?

Comment: Super @Daniel, it is exactly the reason, thanks a lot from newbie~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
return redirect('result', args=(p.id,))
```

Comment: Thanks I tried, but the same error is there. Why there must be a ".html" added in the end?

Comment: .html shouldn't be added. It's probably redirecting you to a template. Please provide more info on your urls.py